# Adding Current Values to future Dates SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to load data for future dates. My scenario is something like this, I have data for 2016, 2017 and 2018(until August). Each year has Current and 'Prior Year Same Day' values associated. Data is aggregated to Month. Requirement is that I load data for future dates as well, that is for September 2018 through August 2019 using 'PYSD' values. For example, the 'Current' value for September 2017 will be 'PYSD' value for September 2018 and so on. When I try this particular logic I get an error stating 'overflow' and I'm unable to figure out what's causing. This happens only with the second condition in my WHERE clause. My SELECT clause aggregates a months' data and outputs as '08-01-2018' - there will be one row per month/year.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(dd, 364, CalendarDate)) AS VARCHAR(250)) 
     + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(dd, 364, CalendarDate)) AS VARCHAR(250)), 2) 
     + '-' + '01' AS MonthPeriod 
FROM
    DateTable 
WHERE  
    DATEADD(DD, 364, CalendarDate) > '08-31-2018' 
    AND DATEADD(DD, 364, CalendarDate) < '08-01-2019'
```

My error:

> Msg 517, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Adding a value to a 'date' column caused an overflow.

Also, open to suggestions if there is a simpler way. I'm on SQL Server.

TIA.

Added sample data:

[image]

Comment: can you show us your schema and sample data ?

Comment: Added sample data. and MAX date in my date table is - '9999-12-31'

Comment: as your max date is `9999-12-31` adding 364 days to it will cause it to overflow. Do you required year 9999 in the dates table ? if not remove the last few years and your query will be fine

Comment: Also as a tip - you should always specify dates as yyyy-mm-dd as it is never ambiguous.

Comment: A year has 365 or 366 days, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I use 364 because it gives me Prior Year Same Day, so I'm comparing Monday of this year to a Monday of Last year and not a Sunday.

Comment: @TomC I have changed the date format still no luck.

Comment: To put it really simple, I just need take 'Current Sales Amount' of July 2018 and assign it as 'PYSD Sales Amount' for July 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated in one of the answers to the original question, your max date is `9999-12-31`

This means that any sort of `DATEADD(DD, 364, CalendarDate)` should always fail. Doesn't matter if you are trying to check against a date in 2018, because it has to do the dateadd first, and that gets an overflow.

To avoid that overflow do your date add the other way - compare the actual CalendarDate to one year *before* your target date.

```
CalendarDate > DATEADD(DD, -364, '08-31-2018')
```

or just

```
CalendarDate > '2017-08-31'
```

I'll leave the rest of how you should specify the date, or whether it should be 364,365,first of month etc to the rest of the discussion.

Comment: I tried every possible combination before posting, except this. It worked! This is what I was looking for and appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What is the maximum date in your DateTable ? You probably have dates that is with year 9999. So adding 364 will cause it to overflow. It has nothing to do with the `SELECT` clause

On your query, you can simply do this

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 
               DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, 
                        DATEADD(DAY, 364, CalendarDate)), 0) AS MonthPeriod
```

Note : 
`DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, <date>), 0)` will gives you the 1st day of the month

EDIT :

The overflow error is because the `DateTable` contains rows with date 9999. Adding 364 days to it will cause over flow.

One quick way to resolve is to delete those rows where year is 9998 or 9999

Another way is to change your query such that it does not add days to the `CalendarDate`

```
WHERE  CalendarDate > DATEADD(DAY, 364, '2018-08-31')
AND    CalendarDate < DATEADD(DAY, 364, '2019-08-01')
```

Note : i uses date string in ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`. It is recommended to specify date in such format as it is unambiguous.

And the complete query will be

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 
               DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, 
                        DATEADD(DAY, 364, CalendarDate)), 0) AS MonthPeriod 
FROM   DateTable
WHERE  CalendarDate > DATEADD(DAY, 364, '2018-08-31')
AND    CalendarDate < DATEADD(DAY, 364, '2019-08-01')
```

Comment: I tried this select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 364, CalendarDate)), 0) AS MonthPeriod from DateTable
where CalendarDate > '08-31-2018' AND CalendarDate < '08-01-2019'
order by CalendarDate and my output starts from '2019-08-01' and ends at '2020-07-01' with 334 rows returned.

Comment: why you change the `WHERE` condition ? should follow your original query

Comment: When I combine your SELECT statement with the WHERE condition in my original query I'm still getting the overflow error, so I changed it and now I get values from 2019 through 2020.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my query per Tom's suggestion and it worked. You both posted similar solutions. Kind of torn between which one to accept as answer. Thanks for all the help!